# integrated (gnome-terminal) zsh vscode \ IDE webstorm

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, webstorm, fedora, integrated

#### Hi all.

I'm having a problem in integrating a customized zsh shell into vscode and webstorm IDE.
By default, both code editors see the path to zsh at zsh, however, vscode writes
'The terminal process "/home/cstrp/zsh" failed to launch (exit code: 1).'  and added path to /usr/bin/zsh vscode writes: 'Value is not accepted. Valid values: null, "sh", "bash", "sh (2)", "bash (2)", "JavaScript Debug Terminal".(1)'
[image]

[image]

###### config vsCode

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        "bash": null,
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh",
            "args": [
                "-l"
            ]
        },
    },
    // "terminal.integrated.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.linux": {
        "path": "zsh",
    },
```

##### default shell

[image]

my pc [image]

Comment: Can you post your $PATH variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was only necessary on behalf of the super user to install all the code editors in the right place